# What does this error mean and how can i solve it

Tags: joi

when i am doing the react-native desktop configuration after installing everything due, when running the comand npx react-native init app gives this error

i tried to see if i was having problems in the place where i stored and if i installed everything that was necessary,

```
Error: Cannot find module 'joi'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\cadma\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\7930a8670f922cdb\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\tools\config\schema.js
- C:\Users\cadma\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\7930a8670f922cdb\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\tools\config\readConfigFromDisk.js
- C:\Users\cadma\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\7930a8670f922cdb\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\tools\config\index.js
- C:\Users\cadma\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\7930a8670f922cdb\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\commands\install\install.js
- C:\Users\cadma\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\7930a8670f922cdb\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\commands\index.js
- C:\Users\cadma\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\7930a8670f922cdb\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js
- C:\Users\cadma\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\7930a8670f922cdb\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at _joi (C:\Users\cadma\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\7930a8670f922cdb\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\tools\config\schema.js:9:39)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\cadma\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\7930a8670f922cdb\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\tools\config\schema.js:26:17)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1155:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What exactly don't you understand about the error? Do you know what a module is? Do you know what "not found" means? Have you heard of the module in question? It's not possible to help you with code unless you show it to us. If you are just trying to install or use *someone else's* code, then that is a tech support question, not a programming question; and Stack Overflow is not the place to ask it.

Answer (score 0):

There is 2 ways to fix them

1. open the folder
   `C:\Users\cadma\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\7930a8670f922cdb\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\` and then run `npm install`
2. delete the cache `C:\Users\cadma\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\7930a8670f922cdb\node_modules\@react-native-community`

Answer (score -1):

Hi it seems you don't have the [Joi](https://www.npmjs.com/package/joi) module installed have you tried running

```
npm install joi
```